# Can functions be overloaded in LISP like they can be in C#?

Tags: lisp, overloading

I find overloading very useful in my C# code. I know it can be done in many other languages too (C++ for sure).

Does LISP allow overloading or something equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does have "something similar", but more powerful: [generic functions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defgen.htm).

**EDIT:** I wasn't aware that the definition of overloading implies compile-time resolution. Thanks Rainer Joswig.

Comment: @Vsevolod Dyomkin Thanks... brain buffer overflow occurred while I was thinking about `defmethod` :)

Comment: Right, but note that generic functions do runtime dispatch, while overloading is resolved at compile time.  Semantically, you can always use generic functions to replace overloading, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Svante I believe I'm seeing a little confusion here. C# also does runtime dispatch, but single: based only on the type of the invoked object, disregarding the runtime type of the arguments.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual, limited dispatch.  What I was talking about is not single versus multiple dispatch, but runtime dispatch versus compile-time overloading, which are fundamentally different.  My comment was meant as a followup to the answer, not your comment.

Comment: CLOS generic functions do not support 'overloading'. CLOS supports dynamic dispatch / polymorphism. Overloading would mean that functions are selected statically by argument types or argument list differences. This is not done with CLOS.

Answer (score 8):

Common Lisp does not.

Common Lisp does not support 'overloading'.

Common Lisp provides polymorphism via CLOS, but not overloading.